# First Line did not delete successfully in file manipulation

Tags: c

I have a code that deletes a specific line from a file. However I have a big problem regarding deleting the line 1. It deletes the line, but it only leaves blank, unlike deleting line 2 and so on.

My file has:

```
1. Mary had a little lamb
2. Twinkle twinkle little stars
3. Baa baa black sheep
```

when I delete line 2, the file would be modified like this:

```
1.Mary had a little lamb
2.Baa baa black shee
```

p
Also, if I delete the line 1, the line will be deleted but the line 1 will be blank. It would be modified like this:

```
1.
2. Baa baa black sheep
```

It may look okay in the console, but when you see in the txt file it is not.

Here's my code:

```
#include 
#define filename "file.txt"
int main()
{
 FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char c;
    int del_line, temp = 1;
    fp1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    c = getc(fp1);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
        c = getc(fp1);
    }

    rewind(fp1);
    printf(" \n Enter line number of the line to be deleted:");
    scanf("%d", &del_line);

    fp2 = fopen("copy.c", "w");

    while( (c = getc(fp1)) != EOF ){
        if (c == '\n')
        temp++;
        if (temp != del_line)
        {
        putc(c, fp2);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    remove(filename);
    rename("copy.c", filename);
    printf("\n The contents of file after being modified are as  follows:\n");
    fp1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    c = getc(fp1);
    while (c != EOF) {
        printf("%c", c);
        c = getc(fp1);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two things: First of all *always* make sure that any function that can fail (like `fopen`) doesn't actually fail; And secondly the [`getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) function returns an **`int`** which is rather important for that comparison against the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: Instead of `if (temp != del_line)` try `if (temp > del_line)`

Comment: As for your problem I recommend you learn how to *debug* your code. Some simple [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should be enough to find the problem, but I also recommend you learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Then the problem should become quite obvious.

Comment: @WeatherVane Or move the `if (c == '\n')` check to later.

Comment: Partially depends on whether you want to delete line 1 or line n.

Answer (score 1):

Your test:

```
if (c == '\n')
```

is before your test:

```
if (temp != del_line)
```

Which means that you're keeping the '\n' of the deleted line.
Hence the fact that, for instance, if you delete the 1st line you get a blank line (i.e. a line constituted solely by its '\n')

A slight modification of your code makes it work:

```
while( (c = getc(fp1)) != EOF ) {
    if (temp != del_line) {
        putc(c, fp2);
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        temp++;
    }
}
```